# html Button on top of link

Tags: html, node.js, reactjs, button

Hey I have a div which is wrapped by a Link component, and inside that div I have more buttons, but the problem is, when I click on the inner smaller buttons, I actually click on the Link component as well, so I get redirected which is not what I want... How do I fix this?

it seems as though both the link and the button get clicked but if i am intending to click the button only i want to avoid the parent link.

What I mean is, the Link is used to navigate to some URL when you click on it. Putting elements inside that for other tasks. like a blog post, you click on the parent it will redirect you, but on the child the button will allow you to delete it

was coding this in nodejs react so i was using onClick events

example

```
<Link to="/blog-post">
  <div className="link-post-container">
      ...blog
      <button className='deleteButton'></button>
  </div>
</Link>
```

I have tried `event.stopPropagation` on the button but it still doesn't seem to do anything. Is it because the Link is an `href` instead of a `onClick`?

**SOLUTION**

so using some of the possible solutions below i started messing around and noticed by in the onClick of the deleteButton, if i add the following in, it works:

```
event.preventDefault()
```

with this, the redirect because of the href does not occur anymore and only the button click event will take place

Answer (score 0):

The click event propagates from the button upwards in the DOM tree until it reaches the root *(simplified explanation - you can learn more about event propagation [here](https://javascript.info/events))*. This is why the link also registers it and runs its onclick handler, redirecting you to another site.

You can call `event.stopPropagation()` inside your button's onClick handler to stop the event from reaching the encapsulating link.

[source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation)

Comment: awesome that is an amazing read, would that even work if the link is not an onClick but an href? i tried that out but was not able to make it work. Does it only apply to onClick? im seeing if i should change my link from an href to onClick

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleClick = event => {
  event.stopPropagation()
  // then write rest of your onclick code 
}


<button className='deleteButton' onClick={handleClick}></button>
```

Comment: i tried that out but it does not work, is it because the parent is not a `onClick` but an `href`?